# Let $p>2$ be a prime number. Prove that $\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \overset{p}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Let $p>2$ be a prime number. Prove that $\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \overset{p}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$

I'm having a hard time with this problem. My approach is as follows: I consider two cases, *(i)* when $(-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} = 1$ and *(ii)* when $(-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} = -1$, and try to prove the congruence for both cases. I approached case *(i)* first, here's what I did:

$\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \overset{p}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \overset{p}\equiv 1 \overset{p}\equiv x^{p-1}$, for some $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. This follows from Fermat's Little Theorem ($x^{p-1}\overset{p}\equiv 1$). From that it follows that $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{p-1}{2}-1\right)!\overset{p}\equiv x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$. But from Fermat's Little Theorem ($x^p\overset{p}\equiv x$) it follows that $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}-1\right)!\overset{p}\equiv 1 \iff \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2\overset{p}\equiv 1 \iff p^2-2p+1 \overset{p}\equiv 4 \implies 4\overset{p}\equiv 1$.

But I don't know how this result will help me, I don't even know if it's correct. As for case *(ii)*, I'm stuck and not sure where to begin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint. Consider the complete residue system $\{ \pm1, \pm2, \ldots, \pm (p-1)/2\}$ instead of the usual $\{1, 2, \ldots, p-1\}$. Multiply everything together (mod $p$) and use Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ a \overset{p}\equiv = -(p - a)$.

Furthermore, since $(p-1)! \overset{p}\equiv -1$ (since this multiplication contains every element and it's inverse exactly once, except for $1$ and $-1$ which are the inverse of themselves, since the equation $x^2 \overset{p}\equiv 1$ has only two solutions $\pm1$).

Therefore,

$ (\frac {p-1} {2}!)^2 \overset{p}\equiv (-1)^{\frac {p-1}{2}}(p-1)! \overset{p}\equiv  (-1)^{\frac {p-1}{2}} (-1) \overset{p}\equiv  (-1)^{\frac {p+1}{2}}$

The main note here is looking at the square of the factorial as a consecutive multiplications of the elements, which practically gives $(p-1)!$ up to some sign corrections, using the observation I wrote at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I don't quite get why $\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2\overset{p}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(p-1)!$

Comment: As I said in the comment, you can think of the factorial squared as writing the factorial twice adjacently - $1*2*...*\frac{p-1}{2}*1*2*....*\frac{p-1}{2}$. Now, in the right half, you have all the "minuses" of the elements $(\frac{p-1}{2}+1)*...*(p-1)$ which together make the $(p-1)!$. So after "taking out" all of the $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ minuses, we get the equality above.